# Set wallpaper from list<Bitmap> using FlipperView

Tags: android, bitmap, viewflipper

I have FlipperView with List and want set wallpaper use myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap), but I didn't understand how to take exact picture that was load in FlipperView as last. 
This is working with sample_0, but didin't if I try change .decodeResource using id. Thanks for any  advance.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sample_0);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_set_wal:
    txtPages.setText("Done");

    try {
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager  = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return true;
}
    return false;

}
```